# If text from file equal name function then run function

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

File `URLs.txt`:

```
$ cat URLs.txt
www.google.com >/path/to/save
```

That's my script:

```
dl_url() {
    while true; do
        while IFS='>' read -r website_url gallery_dir; do
            echo "Downloading $website_url" 
            echo "To $gallery_dir"
            sleep 1
            mkdir -p ./update_photo_temp/
            wget --quiet $website_url -P ./update_photo_temp/

            ## If $website_url = to function then run function
            for i in $website_url; do
                echo $i | awk -F '/.' '{print $2}' | xargs
            done
        done < ./URLs.txt
    done
}

google.com() {
    while true; do
        echo "blah blah blah"
    done
}
```

It's only printing the URLs hostname not start proper function this should start another function depends on URL like google.com start google.com function, how change that?

Comment: Your `for i in $website_url` doesn't make sense to me.   At that point, `$website_url` will be only one URL -- the one that was read at the top of the containing loop.

Comment: Also, if `$website_url` is `www.google.com`, then what do you expect `echo www.google.com | awk -F '/.' '{print $2}'` to print?

Comment: i use that script for i in $website_url from something else and its not working i need only script to run if URL from file are equal to function name like google.com function and run that function google.com

Comment: or other way run function depends on what url are in that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have all those infinitely repeating while loops in there. As Andy pointed out your awk statement is strange and likely not going to do what you want it to. The below script should work better for your purposes.

```
#!/bin/bash
cleanup(){                          
  if [[ ${1} == "www.google.com" ]]; then                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    echo "blah blah blah"           
  else                              
    echo "url not found"            
  fi                                
}                                   

while IFS='>' read -r website_url gallery_dir; do

  echo "Downloading $website_url"   
  echo "To $gallery_dir"; sleep 1   
  mkdir -p ./update_photo_temp/     
  wget --quiet $website_url -P ./update_photo_temp/

  for i in $website_url; do         
    cleanup ${i}                    
  done                              

done < ./URLs.txt
```

Comment: i have many and big functions for each urls many lines of code

Comment: yes thats script looks much better i can use it but how to cut only the google.com part from url file? i mean whole url is longer like www.google.com/blah/bla/bla, should be there awk command to print only google.com not whole url then run your script

Comment: i think im gonna use new variable like hostname= awk command to print only host not all url and run this script. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title, as I understood it: You want to read lines of input, and for each that is equal to the name of a shell function, run that function.

You can use `declare -f func` to see if `func` is defined, so something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() { echo foofoo; }
bar() { echo barbar; }
while read funcname; do
    if declare -f "$funcname" &> /dev/null; then
        "$funcname"
    fi
done
```

Note that in your code:

```
IFS='>' read -r website_url gallery_dir
```

leaves the space before `>` in `website_url`, since the `IFS` you set here doesn't contain any whitespace. You could use `IFS='> ' read ...` instead.

```
for i in $website_url; do
    echo $i | awk -F '/.' '{print $2}' | xargs
done
```

I'm not sure what this is supposed to do. `for i in $website_url` splits and globs the value of the variable, and has `i` loop over the values. The `xargs` at the end of the pipeline echoes whatever it gets as input. None of that runs any functions. Also, the `awk` field separator `/.` matches a slash followed by any character, so if the input was e.g. `foo/bar`, the resulting output would be `ar`.